# How to integrate ConTeXt package from pragma into TeXLive?

Tags: context

Have anyone an idea how to integrate the cont-tmf.zip into TeXLive distibution?

The standalone distribution works not and so I would like an integration of up-to-date distribution within the texmf-tree.

Thanks in advance,
Thomas

Comment: What do you mean by "The standalone distribution works not"? It works very well here, and I have it living side-by-side with texlive.

Comment: It won't  work the newer context files need a newer  luatex version. So the standalone version is your only option unless you are willing to exchange the binary too.

Comment: Do you speak German?  There was a talk by Herbert Voß at DANTE 2014 about this topic: https://www.dante.de/events/Herbst2014/Programm/Vortraege/voss.pdf